# Importar ficheiros CSV para o MySQL utilizando LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, csv

Usei o seguinte script para importar um ficheiro `.csv` para o MySQL utilizando o `MySQL WorkBench`:

```
USE test;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'exemplo1.csv' INTO TABLE tabela1 fields terminated by ';' lines terminated by '\r';
```

Vi em vários outros sites utilizando apenas o comando `LOAD DATA INFILE`, porém o meu script só funciona adicionando a palavra-chave `LOCAL`. Alguém sabe dizer para que funciona? E qual o objectivo de ser ou não usado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A palavra-chave `LOCAL` é utilizado quando o arquivo está em outra máquina da que o MySQL está executando.

Ao adicionar o `LOCAL` o arquivo será enviado para o servidor, armazenado em uma pasta temporária, e rodar a partir daí. Isto funciona apenas se as permissões necessárias estiverem definidas.

Comment: então mas o meu ficheiro .csv esta na mesma maquina da que o MySQL esta a executar, ou o facto de ter utilizado o XAMPP dado que preciso de aceder a um servidor remoto?

Comment: @Rodrigo Nesse caso é preciso informar o local do arquivo, por exemplo: 'C:\\Documentos\\arquivo.csv'